# How to get a country's official languages?

Tags: geography

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_languages)

> Of the 193 widely recognized countries, 178 have an official language at the national level

(NB:or more than one)

The only exceptions are:

> Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Eritrea, The Holy See, Luxembourg, San Marino, Sweden, Tuvalu, Ukraine, United Kingdom, United States, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, and Yemen

`CountryData[]` supports three language related properties:

> "Languages", "LanguagesDialects", "LanguagesFractions"

But none of them seems to return the "Official Languages".

Is there a way to get a country's official languages within Mathematica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the undocumented option `OfficialLanguages`

```
CountryData["Republic of South Africa", "OfficialLanguages"]
```

> {"Afrikaans", "English", "IsiZulu", "IsiXhosa", "Sepedi", "Swati",
>   "Ndebele", "Sesotho", "Xitsonga", "Setswana", "Venda"}

Comment: how did you find the undocumented option?

Comment: Still not completely right answers (at least comparing with Wikipedia results). But at least it's an internal solution. Well done :)

Comment: @belisarius Comparing to wiki - yes, but if memory serves me well we have mentioned in primary that the country with most official languages is Republic of South Africa. That was some years ago, so it may have changed...

Comment: @PatoCriollo Honestly - just playing around :D

Comment: From Wikipedia: _"However, in the plurinational state of Bolivia, Article 5-1 of the Constitution recognises 37 official languages"_

Comment: @belisarius Never been there, can't confirm :D

Comment: But **I** did :)

Comment: Xhosa is a very interesting language, due to its clicks. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZlp-croVYw

Comment: `CountryData` seems pretty weak at identifying official languages. `CountryData["India", "OfficialLanguages"]` gives `{"Hindi", "English"}`. I believe there are a lot more. I know, for example, that Urdu is one.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yup, India was my first try :D

Comment: @m_goldberg [Only Hindi and English are the official languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_India#Official_languages). Individual states can set their own official language...

Answer (score 2):

what about.

```
    {#, WolframAlpha[
        StringJoin["Official Language ", #], {{"Result", 1}, 
         "ComputableData"}]} & /@ {"Argentina", "Belgium", "Belarus", 
      "Ireland", "Ukraine"}
     (*{{"Argentina", {"Spanish"}}, {"Belgium", {"Dutch", "French", 
        "German"}}, {"Belarus", {"Belarusan","Russian"}}, {"Ireland",{"English",""}}, {"Ukraine", {"Ukrainian"}}}*)
```

Comment: Please try with China or Bolivia (and compare with the corresponding Wikipedia entries). They are making the world's data computable, but they aren't still there