# CountryData vs EntityProperty: why do different data access methods produce different results?

Tags: curated-data, entity

Illustrative example: using `CountryData` we are told the data is missing, but we can nevertheless access it via an `EntityProperty`.  Shouldn't these provide the same result?

```
us = Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]
CountryData[us, {"GDP", 2013}]  (* fails *)
gdp2013 = EntityProperty["Country", "GDP", {"Date" -> DateObject[{2013}]}]
us[gdp2013]  (* succeeds *)
```

Comment: They probably should.  I would report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: It's even more worrisome than just not returning some values; the two approaches report slightly *different* values for the same year. Try e.g. 2008. I guess they fish for data in different pools... I would second @chuy's advice to report this to support.

Comment: OK, I reported it.

Comment: The case of `CountryData` is discussed in both responses to [Finding out all undocumented values for “Properties” in XxxData functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66324/142).  It is not clear to me whether or not the present question should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @WReach  This is an entirely different problem.  E.g., if we change the 2nd line of the example to `CountryData[us, {"GDP", 2008}]` it succeeds.  Also, see the comment of @MarcoB.

Comment: It seems this has been fixed.  Using version 10.3.1 I get the same answer from both queries.